# Using jquery for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm trying to use the auto-complete with jQuery with the help of this.
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete
But when i use this block

```
      create_table :srch do |t|
         t.column :name, :string
      end
```

It gives out a error saying: undefined method `create_table' for main:Object.

Can you suggest something to tackle this error?

This is my controller code:

```
        class ProductsController < ApplicationController

         def new

          @product = Srch.new
         end

         def result 
         end

         def show

           @site_matches = Srch.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
         end

         autocomplete :srch, :name do |items|
           CustomJSON::Encoder.encode(items)
         end
         end
```

This is my view file:

```
               <h1>Results for your search.</h1>
               <%= render "products/new"%>
               <%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js"%>

           <table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Max. Price</th><th>Min. Price</th><th>Discount</th><th>Image</th></tr>

       <% for prod in @site_matches %>
       <tr><td><%= prod.name %></td><td><%= prod.maxprice%></td><td><%= prod.minprice%></td><td><%= prod.discount%></td><td> <%= image_tag(prod.image, :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %> </td></tr>

                <% end %>
                </table>
                </br>
```

And this is model code:

```
                class Srch < ActiveRecord::Base
                end

                create_table :srches do |t|
                t.column :name, :string
                end
```

Comment: check your configuration (Installing part of the github link)

Comment: No t a good question. Add more code.